# How to load an iOS framework on apps targeting iOS 7 and avoid error in XCode 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

We are currently having the following error while loading the framework when we set a target earlier to iOS 8. We got the issue only after upgrading to XCode 7.

> ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later
>   (@rpath/xxx.framework/xxx) for architecture armv7

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic frameworks were not supported in iOS apps before iOS 8 and I assume `xxx.framework` is a dynamic framework.

Static frameworks, on the other hand, have been supported for a long time.

You will have do one of the following:

1. Set the deployment target to iOS 8.
2. Find a static version of `xxx.framework`.